# Multiple repositories for modules in android studio

Tags: android, git, git-submodules

I am trying to convert my existing application into a number of modules.

Is it possible for me to have each module pointing to a git repository so I can grant access to people accordingly?

So my structure is like this

```
  APP --> Git 1
      Module 1 --> Git 2
      Module 2 --> Git 3
     ...
```

Is this possible for me to do with an android studio project?

The idea is for me to be able to give different developers different modules and not let them access other modules. I have never used git this extensively so dont really know how this works

Please help

Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Android studio supports multiple git repos.

you will have something like:

```
Repositories:
Repo 1 -> master
Repo 2 -> feature/branch-name
```

in AS Select VCS, VCS popup and import or check out repo. Or you can create new repo in your folder and and independently in subfolders.